# The routine has been declared twice in the same file

Tags: coldfusion

We are testing our move to CF2021. We repeatedly get this error of function declared twice in same file. We have tried removing the function and error moves to the next function in cfc.

Same thing works on CF2016 & CF2018 without any issues. Any help, what could be going on here?

Comment: I'd start by clearing out yer cfclasses dir, perhaps. I'm less surprised about CF2021 erroring, and more than the earlier versions were apparently not: this has been illegal in CF since... functions were first added in CF5. And it certainly does error for me on CF2016 and CF2018 as well. How did you get into the situation of declaring the same functions multiple times in the same file?

Comment: Is this using the REST API stuff at all? If you have the a file which has another identical file but with different filename in the same directory, you get this kind of error too.

Comment: Are you using `include` by any chance? Can you reproduce the issue with a stripped down version of your component file?

Comment: @haxtbh, it is not REST API stuff. But we sure have few backup files of the same file in which reported in same directory.

Comment: @AdamCameron, I am not sure I got you completely. I will try by clearing cfclasses directory. How did I got into this situation? There are no functions with same name, not in this file not in whole codebase.

Comment: @Alex, No. No includes.

Comment: Are the functions causing the error functions that your company created? Like `someFunctionToDoAThing()` or do the functions have the same name as CF native functions that are new to CF 2021? With CF 9, we created a function in the root `component.cfc` file named `encodeForHTML()` to expose the underlying Java library function. CF 10 made that a native function, so we just removed our user-defined version to avoid the "declared twice" error.

Comment: "There are no functions with same name, not in this file not in whole codebase". That wording  makes it sound like it's only happening in one file. What's different about the usage of this one file?

Answer (score 0):

I would check if you have multiple cfincludes that have the same routine in it. I had same happen and it considered the routine in the cfinclude declared twice.

Answer (score 0):

We finally found this line of code causing the trouble. No idea why. But posting this as answer, if someone runs into similar issue. Removing it made that error go away.

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
```